# Docker: The command '/bin/sh -c configure.sh' returned a non-zero code: 22

Tags: docker, shell, travis-ci, ubuntu-22.04, open-liberty

I have a Java application and it uses liberty server. My Dockerfile has suddenly stopped working in Travis. Although, it builds locally but it's not working in my Travis pipeline.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
FROM open-liberty:full-java11-openj9

USER root

COPY --chown=1001:0 /deploy/defaultServer/server.xml /config/
COPY --chown=1001:0 /deploy/defaultServer/apps/app.war /config/apps/

ARG VERBOSE=true

RUN configure.sh

RUN apt-get update
```

Command used to build docker image -

```
docker build --tag app:${TRAVIS_BUILD_ID} . --no-cache --progress=plain
```

I get below error in Travis while building docker image -

```
Step 7/8 : RUN configure.sh
 ---> Running in d67ac92aad57
The command '/bin/sh -c configure.sh' returned a non-zero code: 22
```

This error code does not help much. What can I do to get more details on the error?

**Edit -**
After adding `ARG VERBOSE=true`, I saw some logs, and it all seemed fine until the end. This is what came up towards the end -

```
Starting server defaultServer.
Server defaultServer start failed. Check server logs for details.
The command '/bin/sh -c configure.sh' returned a non-zero code: 22
```

Where do I get server logs? What is causing the server start to fail?

Comment: Are you sure configure.sh is at WORKDIR and not any other location? Also, according to your second try with chmod +x it seems that the script is not at /, which doesn't mean anything bad on its own...

Comment: ok, forgive me, i looked at open-liberty:full-java11-openj9, configure.sh comes from there so as you're not changing your WORKDIR all should be fine... Your try with chmod should be without the leading '/', i'm guessing

Comment: Still gives the same error with RUN chmod +x configure.sh.

Comment: The problem in step 7/8 isn't a permission error. If it were a permission error you wouldn't be told it returned an error code 22, you'd get a different error. If you set VERBOSE=true you will get more information on what went wrong.

Comment: (You've misspelled `VERBOSE` in the line above the troublesome `RUN` line.)

Comment: I added verbose flag and re-ran the build. I've added the details in the question! @DavidMaze

Comment: Why you have 2 `FROM` lines? You should have only the one with liberty